# Select a specific range on a specific row

Tags: excel, vba

I need to select a range from `”A1”` until the cell with value e.g “Next Due Date” on the same row. 
I tried the below code and got Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error at  `ActiveSheet.Range("A1:" & colMark).Select`

```
Const markName As String = "Next Due Date"

Dim colMark As Range

Set colMark = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find(What:=markName, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole) 'determinte the colMark column
  
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:" & colMark).Select
```

Comment: what is inside of `colMark` ?

Comment: You have to use the `Address` property of the range: `ActiveSheet.Range("A1:" & colMark.Address).Select`

Comment: @Ike I tried and it works

Comment: Please, try `Range("A1", colMark).Select

Comment: One of the higher active Excel related questions is about avoiding select in Excel VBA. Tell me, why do you want to select a range of cells? Do you want to delete them, alter their format, modify their content, copy them, ...? (In almost all those cases, selecting the range is not even needed)

Comment: @FaneDuru I tried and it also works, indeed it is the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the fact that `colMark` is a Range variable, the term "A1:" & colMark will fail because the VBA compiler assumes that you want to concatenate the string "A1" with *content* of the cell `colMark`. This doesn't result in a valid range address and therefore you get the error.

There are several ways to define a Range in VBA that you could use:

**o** Concatenate "A1:" and the *address* of colMark:

```
Range("A1:" & colMark.address)
```

**o** Use the `Range`-method that takes 2 parameters (start and end cell):

```
Range(Cells(1, 1), colMark)
Range(Range("A1"), colMark)
```

**o** Use the `Resize`-method

```
Range("A1").Resize(1, colMark.Column)
```

Note that you almost never need to select a Range. Also, you should always specify on which worksheet you want to work (so my examples above are bad code, I just wanted to show the different methods). If your following code needs to work on that range, you can use for example a `Range` variable:

```
Dim myWorkRange as Range
Dim colMark As Range

With ActiveSheet     ' Can be replaces with whatever sheet you want to work with
    Set colMark = .Rows(1).Find(What:=markName, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole) 
    Set myWorkRange = .Range("A1", colMark.Address)
End With
myWorkRange.Interior.Color = vbYellow    ' Just to give the idea
```